# Show random images based on the random generated number they have in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, random, android-image

I made a random number generator. When I press a button it will generate a number from 1 to 999. The number is shown on a text view but I made it invisible so it can work in the background. I also added some images but made them invisible. What I want to do now is give the images a certan number for example 1 to 100. Based on the number my generator generates, the images will become visible again.
You know like giving the different picture different chances to show .
Can someone help me with this problem? I also did the same thing in the school but that was in pascal and I can't remember the code anymore.

EDIT

Firstly I want to apologize that my question was so vague, I was frustrated and tired and posted this question so badly because I did not care

What I want to do is a small gamble game where the player presses a button and then a random image pops up showing what he won. I tried to achieve that with the following code.

```
my Java file looks like this

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public ImageView imageView;
public ImageView imageView2;
public ImageView imageView3;
public ImageView imageView4;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    imageView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    imageView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    imageView4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
public void generator (View view) {
    Random rand= new Random();
    int number = rand.nextInt(999)+1;

    TextView shownumber = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cases);
    String mystring = String.valueOf(number);
    shownumber.setText(mystring);
    switch (number){
        case 1-250:
            imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        case 251-400:
            imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        case 401-600:
            imageView3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            imageView3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        case 601-1000:
            imageView4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            imageView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
    }
}
}
```

But when I start the app, the generated numbers are still shown on the text view but the images won't become visible again.
Anyone has a solution for this problem?

Comment: What have you tried so far in regards to displaying the images? can you provide any code for us to work with?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

1. Create an Array which will hold your images like this,

   ```
   int Images[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2....};
   ```
2. Now when a random number is generated you can use that number as an index to your array

   for example if number 5 is generated, it would be like `Images[5]`

Comment: Note: Image number 5 would be Images[4] not Images[5]